# Error: .post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to node/express and I keep getting this exception.

> Error: .post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

with this code

```
nu = require('./routes/create_newissue.js');
app.post('/create_newissue',nu.resources);
```

The code in `exports.create_newissue` works fine if I put it in app.js. However, if I put it in a seperate `.js` file it throws the above error.

Answer (score 16):

You must have something like this in `create_newissue.js`

```
exports.resources = function(req, res){
   // Your code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gilberto, I have this:
exports.create_newissue = function(req, res) the thing that throws seems to be app.post('/create_newissue',nu.resources); I have tried this with app.get and no problem...

Comment: Thanks for the input, not sure why but exports.someresource does not work in a seperate .js file it has to be in my app.js? So if I want to use app.post I have to cram them all together in 1 file?!?

Answer (score 4):

The Error you've got indicates that the **nu.resources** you've sent to **app.post(**  isn't a function.

I'm not sure what you've done, because you didn't give much of your code...

but this is the structure you need to have:

**app.js:** 
usually you put all the routes in a different file and add it to app.js like this:

```
 require('./routes')(app);
```

but it should also work if you do it direcly from app.js instead of routes.js

**routes.js**

```
var nu = require('./path/nu');
module.exports = function (app) {
          app.post('/create_newissue',nu.resourcesFunc);
    };
```

**nu.js**

```
exports.resourcesFunc = function (req, res) {
    //TODO: do your stuff here...
};
```

---

for summary, double check that you give a **function (req, res) {...}** to **app.post()** as it should be:

```
app.post('/address',function (req, res) {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

problem with importing the file. In your case you missed parenthesis
It should be 
nu = require('./routes/create_newissue.js')();

Answer (score 0):

Check is there is typo error while importing your functions. I had the same issue on checking I have done some spelling mistake.